# Why does new Date(1970, 0 ,1).getFullYear() return 1969?

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain why `new Date(1970, 0 ,1).getFullYear()` returns `1969` and not `1970`?

```js
result.textContent = new Date(1970, 0, 1).getFullYear();
```

```html
<div id=result></div>
```

---

Filed Firefox Bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1093130

Comment: It returns 1970 for me in IE.

Comment: Returns 1970 in Chrome 38

Comment: 1970 for me in Chrome (OSX) **but '1969' in Firefox!**

Comment: Your snippet says 1970 for me. Mac, Chrome 38.

Comment: 1970 Chrome 38.
http://screencast.com/t/lSfCJXhFp9Q

Comment: Wow, this must be Firefox only! Will file bug.

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: 1970 using ff 32.0.3 in Win 7

Comment: I get the same thing (also in England). 1970 in Chrome, 1969 in Firefox.

Comment: @wilsonpage: Do you happen to be using \*nix?

Comment: I'm on OSX, is that what you mean?

Comment: @wilsonpage: Yes indeed, as OSX is in the Unix family of OSes, being a branch of NextStep, which in turn is a branch of BSD.

Comment: @wilsonpage: Out of curiousity, when you run my snippet on your box, do you get a timezone suffix (BST, GMT) and if so, which do you get?

Comment: Wed Dec 31 1969 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (BST)

Comment: @wilsonpage: So that part is common too!

Answer (score 7):

Looks a lot like a timezone bug in Firefox's SpiderMonkey engine (most likely in some library it uses); in my experimentation it only affects *nix OSes, not Windows. (See below for why timezones come into it.) It's returning

```
Wed Dec 31 1969 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (BST)
```

...when of course, we (@wilsonpage, myself, and millions others on UK time) aren't on British Summer Time anymore (and when we *are* on summer time, it's GMT+0100, not GMT-0100, so it wouldn't make sense for local time to be *behind* UTC in any case). (Side note: Chrome also shows "BST", but it has the correct date/time.) (Note for Americans: You're used to "xST" meaning "x *standard* time" [as opposed to "x *daylight* time"], but here BST stands for "British Summer Time" — e.g., daylight savings time. When we're not on summer time, we're in GMT.)

I see this behavior in Firefox 30 on Linux Mint 16 (apparently the latest in the packages system) and Firefox 33 on that same system (just downloaded and installed from Mozilla directly); I do **not** see it on Firefox 33 on Windows 8.1.

@wilsonpage has confirmed that he's using OS X and that he's seeing the same time I am (including the "BST" part).

```js
result.textContent = new Date(1970, 0, 1).toString();
```

```html
<div id=result></div>
```

---

The reason timezones come into it (and apparently trigger the bug) is that the values you give that version of the [`Date` constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) are interpreted as UTC, but [`getFullYear`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.10) returns its value in local time.

Answer (score 0):

I met a bug here as well: I'm in Dublin, GMT time, but Date() will show me

```
"Fri Nov 07 2014 16:17:25 GMT+2359 (GMT)"
```

Look at the timezone offset. I'm one day ahead (or better: +00.00 MINUS 1 minute gives +23.59).

FF31.2.0 on Centos 7

I have no idea how to overcome this problem :(